# VirtualBox Headless: Unable to create hostonly network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, headless

I am trying to create VM with the one Bridged interface and one Hostonly interface, but I keep getting an error as the I am not able to attach a device to the hostonly nic. I have done this:

```
# vboxmanage hostonlyif create
# vboxmanage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 10.0.0.10 --netmask 255.255.255.0
# vboxmanage createvm --name "centos604" --register --basefolder /vboxes
# vboxmanage modifyvm "centos604" --memory 512 --acpi on --boot1 dvd --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0 --nic2 hostonly --hostonlyadapter1 vboxnet0 --ostype RedHat_64
# vboxmanage createvdi --filename /vboxes/centos604hdd.vdi --size 10000
# vboxmanage storagectl "centos604" --name "IDE Controller" --add ide"
# vboxmanage storageattach "centos604" --storagectl "IDE Controller"  --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium /vboxes/centos604hdd.vdi 
# vboxmanage storageattach "centos604" --storagectl "IDE Controller"  --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium CentOS-6.4-x86_64-minimal.iso 
# vboxmanage startvm
# vboxmanage startvm "centos604" --type headless
Waiting for VM "centos604" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: Nonexistent host networking interface, name '' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Console, interface IConsole
```

And here is the output of my ip:

```
# ip addr show vboxnet0
15: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.10/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global vboxnet0
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is my error:

```
Nonexistent host networking interface, name
```

Comment: :) Ask Ubuntu doesn't work like a forum. Instead of using "SOLVED" we [accept answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) to tell people we found a solution. See the [FAQ] and [about] pages for more information.

Answer (score 4):

I have figured out with some trial and error, that the "--hostadapter1" in the command

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "centos604" --memory 512 --acpi on --boot1 dvd --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0 --nic2 hostonly --hostonlyadapter1 vboxnet0 --ostype RedHat_64
```

should actually be replaced with the "--hostadapter2"

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "centos604" --memory 512 --acpi on --boot1 dvd --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0 --nic2 hostonly --hostonlyadapter2 vboxnet0 --ostype RedHat_64
```

And it works fine.

Comment: Do you mean "--hostonlyadapter1" and "--hostonlyadapter2"?